# Performance Benchmark CouchDB x Relational Databases

Tags: performance, couchdb, benchmarking

Does anyone knows a link for a good performance benchmark of CouchDB x "Any relational Database"

Answer (score 2):

Not a performance benchmark, but also significantly more "real world".

http://johnpwood.net/2009/08/18/couchdb-the-last-mile/

Answer (score 0):

Someone tried... http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2009/08/document-oriented-data-stores.html

Comment: Quote from the document you linked: "When i ran the scripts i found that it was crashing a lot. So, i did not go ahead with a proper testing of couchdb." :) I guess this tells us how well those scripts were written...

Comment: Terrible test.It doesn't even test concurrency.