# How is CouchDB at OLAP?

Tags: couchdb

I have a data-table consisting of a large number (say, a billion) of vectors `[ x1, x2, x3 ]` and I want to ask typical OLAP questions like "for all vectors with x1 in a given range, what is the average value of v3?"  Unlike true OLAP, the questions are not *ad-hoc*: I have only a handful of pre-defined questions.

In a SQL database, you can say that if the columns are un-indexed, the space requirements are O(n) and so is the time; indexing gives you O(log n) for time at the cost of O(n log n) for space.

So, is CouchDB roughly equivalent, performance-wise?  Much better?  Much worse?

Comment: If you have a handful of queries AND you can express them with Map/Reduce, couch will be faster because the value of v3 would be precomputed and the answer updated on every update. Putting this in as a comment because I have not done this particular style in practice and hopefully someone else with experience will answer.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296741/performance-benchmark-couchdb-x-relational-databases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB will generally be worse if you want to do ad-hoc queries, and better if you have pre-baked queries.

This is just a technical point about CouchDB, not NOSQL vs. SQL.

CouchDB is a little slower at ad-hoc queries, which I think require table scans. But views incrementally update as you incrementally add data, so it's good for maintaining stuff like "Sum", "Count" or anything else that can be Map-Reduced.

Comment: +1 very pithy. The way I say it is, SQL is good when you know more about the data and less about the questions you'll ask; CouchDB is good when you know less about the data and more about the questions you ask.